# Did patenting exist in the magical world?

Tags: harry-potter

**Did the concept of patenting inventions exist in the magical world?**

This is in reference to the "Patented Daydream Charms" mentioned by the Weasely's brothers in the Weasley's Wizarding Wheezes (Half-Blood Prince).

So, I was wondering whether the concept of patenting existed? Or was it just a part of the "cool product naming" of the Weasley's startup?

If yes, then are there any other instances in the book, where it is mentioned or something which signals/proves it's existence?

Comment: There’s the Ludicrous Patents Office in the Ministry of Magic (*Order of the Phoenix*); does that count?

Comment: @alexwlchan - I was just about to post that as an answer.

Comment: @alexwlchan Ahh. Didn't pop up in my mind.  Thanks for pointing out. Wondering whether there are any canonical details about that Office?

Comment: @Valorum Do go ahead and add it as an answer :)  (Pl do also add any more canonical details about the Office)

Comment: @Dawny33 - Nope. Just a throwaway line in one book

Comment: @alexwlchan *"Ludicrous Patents Office in the Ministry of Magic"* WOAH! Haven't heard of that. Thinking about some Apple patents… is this the USPTO? Wizards are real! :O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, there are a few mentions of patents.**

- When Harry’s in the lift in the Ministry of Magic:

  > “Level seven, Department of Magical Games and Sports, incorpo- rating the British and Irish Quidditch League Headquarters, Official Gobstones Club, and **Ludicrous Patents Office**.”
  >
  > — *Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 7 (*The Ministry of Magic*)

  We don’t know anything more about what this department does.
- In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*:

  > Though Chizpurfles are easy enough to destroy with any of a number of **patented potions** on the market
- In *Quidditch Through the Ages*, the section entitled *The Development of the Racing Broom* mentions the “**patented Horton-Keitch braking charm**”.

Comment: Wow!  Appreciate the efforts behind the answer :)

Comment: Interestingly, JKR also uses the word in the non-literal sense; "*But they still have a lot of affection for their siblings, and go out of their way to make sure they feel included. Whether forcing Percy to wear **the patented Weasley Christmas jumper**, or doing Quidditch training with their younger siblings every holidays, the twins know that family is important.*" - https://www.pottermore.com/features/6-reasons-why-we-wish-weasley-twins-were-our-brothers

Comment: I seem to recall that Fred and George patented some of their inventions, but I could well be mistaken!

Comment: @OftenRight Such as the “Patented Daydream Charms” mentioned in the question?

Comment: @alexwlchan Yep, that'd be it!